# Regex C#- Everything Before, Between and After [T][/T]

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I've this regex

```
([\s\S]*?)\[T\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/T\]([\s\s]*?)
```

Which is supposed to extract everything before, between and after `[T][\T]`, but I always get the third capturing group empty.

My text is:

```
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>
[T]
 <h2>I'm Inside</h2
[/T]
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>
[T]
 <h2>I'm Inside</h2
[/T]
<h3>By World</h3>
```

I've used [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) and [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) And came to the conclusion that the mistake was in the `?` on the last capturing group `([\s\S]*?)`, beacuse is doing the `*` lazy. However if I remove it it groups everything as a single match instead of two.

**EDIT:**

Basically I want to do something like

```
var template = @"    <h1>HelloWorld</h1>
    [T]
     <h2>I'm Inside</h2
    [/T]
    <h1>HelloWorld</h1>
    [T]
     <h2>I'm Inside</h2
    [/T]
    <h3>By World</h3>";

var regex = new Regex("([\s\S]*?)\[T\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/T\]([\s\s]*?)");
var finalString = regex.Replace(template,"$1 ; $2 ; $3");

// finalString = HelloWorld ; I'm Inside ; By World //
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify (more specific) what the desired result is ? Because as far as i see this regex selects everything (including [T] and [/T] tags) except the last line.

Comment: Ready, made an edit, and yeah, it's pretty simple. I want to select everything, including the last line, that is where the error happens.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear as you are trying to capture text inside tags, and output text without tags - it is not possible with 1 pass. `h2` tag is not closed with `>` - is that really what you have? `[\s\s]` makes no sense, it is equal to `\s`. For now, I can only suggest http://ideone.com/upIXLR, please check and update.

Comment: Sorry, my bad it is \s\S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question title controverts with the actual output example, my answer is based on the actual desired output.

To get the desired output, you have to look at the patterns in the given text. The text you want to capture is **not** always between [T][/T]. But it's always between **>**...**<**

Based on that logic i made an example for you:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<=\>).+?(?=\<)");

var matches = reg.Matches(content);

// get distinct result
var result = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// build the string
foreach (var item in result)
{
    builder.Append(item).Append(" ; ");
}

// remove last added " ; "
builder.Length = builder.Length - 3;

// builder now equals "HelloWorld ; I'm Inside ; By World"
Console.WriteLine(builder);
```